# Get consuming service's package.name inside an npm package

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have the following

```
consuming-service
-package.json (has utilities-package as a dependency)
```

```
utilities-package (published to npm)
-package.json
-version.js
```

I'm trying to make version.js return the consuming service's name and version, but I'm not sure how to access `consuming-service`'s package.json from within `utilities-package`

version.js

```js
const pkg = require('../../package.json') // this doesn't work
function getVersion () {
 return {
    name: pkg.name,
    version: pkg.version,
  }
}
```

I'm struggling with finding the specific terms to google to find my answer.

Comment: Do `process.env.npm_package_name` and `process.env.npm_package_version` suit your needs? [Reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars)

Comment: @RickyMo consuming-service would have to know to set those values for utilities-package to work.

Comment: if you run the process by `npm start`, those values are automatically set.

Answer (score 0):

The two best answers I have found are:

1. Use `process.env.npm_package_name` & `process.env.npm_package_version`. These values are automatically set if the consuming service is run with `npm start` or `yarn start`
2. Pass the package.json into the `getVersion` function.

```js
// utilities-package/version.js
function getVersion (pkg) {
 return {
    name: pkg.name,
    version: pkg.version,
  }
}
```

```js
// consuming-service
const utils = require('utilities-package')
const pkg = require('../../package.json')
const versionResult = utils.getVersion(pkg)
```